# How can I make a msgbox appear on a Userform when the person enters a specific value

Tags: excel, vba, userform, msgbox

I have created a userform in Excel which will populate a database.  However, there is a combobox in my userform where the user selects a specific rate from a list of three.  When one specific rate is selected, I need to show an error message immediately.  I have other error messages that will show when the user selects to 'Submit' the form, but I need this one to populate as soon as the value is selected.  I have corrected my other coding issue so this should not be related to that.

The code that I have so far is here:

```vb
Private Sub cmbMileageRates_Change()

    If cmbMileageRates.Value = ".58" Then
        MsgBox "When requesting mileage reimbursement of the high rate($.58/mile), Division Administrator Approval is required", 0, "Critical"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use event "cmbMileageReimbRates_change"?

```
Private Sub cmbMileageReimbRates_Change()
If cmbMileageReimbRates.Value = ".58" Then
    MsgBox "When requesting mileage reimbursment of the high rate ($.58/mile), Division 
     Administrator Approval is required", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire your code when the form is 'dirty'.

The **Dirty** event occurs when the contents of the specified control changes.

There is a good example of this on the Microsoft Website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.dirty

```
    Private Sub Form_Dirty() 
     If Me.Dirty Then 
        If cmbMileageReimbRates.value = ".58" Then
            MsgBox "When requesting mileage reimbursment of the high rate ($.58/mile), Division Administrator Approval is required", vbCritical

            'if you want to clear the value too, use:
            cmbMileageReimbRates.Value = Null
            Exit Sub
        End If
     Else 
        'Carry on
     End If 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Like this?  Because it isn't working?    Private Sub cmbMileageReimbRate_Dirty()
 If cmbMileageReimbRate.Dirty Then
      If cmbMileageReimbRates.value = ".58" Then
            MsgBox "When requesting mileage reimbursment of the high rate ($.58/mile), Division Administrator Approval is required", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
      End If
End Sub

Comment: You are missing an 'End If' in your example.  Does the code fire?  Can you debug the code?

Comment: When i debug my code, it takes me to the userform, I enter the .58 selection and it takes me back to the code with the message box text highlighted.  I then hit F8 and it continues to debug.  I suspect maybe now I have something else going on someplace else in my coding since my 'submit' button isn't working anymore either.  Back to the drawing board.